# Error con SwipeRefresh android

Tags: android

Hola resulta que no he podido configurar el SwRefresh en android creo tener todo bien pero no me reconoce el evento, me tira este error: Cannot resolve symbol

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SwipeRefreshLayout mswipeRefreshLayout;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mswipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);

    }


mswipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            //write your code here.
            //
            mswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: ¿Estas usando AndroidX?, podrías agregar tu `build.gradle`

Comment: "Cannot resolve symbol" te falto indicar que valor es el que indica.Agrega el mensaje de error completo e indica en el código cual es la variable que menciona el error.